# Make save as in the same path & name without prompt

Tags: excel, vba

Requirements:

1. Protect all sheets
2. Hide all sheets except PERMISSIONS sheet
3. Add password to the file and save it in the same path with same name without prompt

The below code does not seems to work properly. It does not apply file protection.

Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Dim a110w As Variant
    Dim path As String
    
    
    a110w = "123" 'P
    path = Application.ThisWorkbook.path
    
 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
          
          ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:=a110w 'Unprotect workbook structure
          
         For Each Worksheet In Sheets 'Protect all sheets
          
              Worksheet.Protect Password:=a110w
         Next
    
         For Each Worksheet In Sheets 'Hide all sheets except PERMISSIONS sheet
          
             If Not Worksheet.Name = "Permissions" Then Worksheet.Visible = xlVeryHidden
          Next
          
    With ThisWorkbook
       .SaveAs Filename:=path, FileFormat:=50, Password:=a110w
       
    End With
         
          
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
          
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: When all else fails, check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.protect).

Comment: Do not use `Worksheet` as a variable for this is a built in object type. Try using something like `ws` or whatever else.